# How to delete old commit from GitHub

Tags: github, commit

Three commits ago I accidentally pushed a modified file to my GitHub repo with some personal data what I don't want to have on github. I removed it and pushed again. The problem is, if someone is browsing the history it's still there. Is it possible to just delete that commit by the commit-ID or something?

Comment: If you can remove the file from your branch entirely (e.g. filter branch, `rebase -i` to squash together the commits that add and remove it, etc.) you could then force-push that to GitHub in place of the current branch, and casual browsers wouldn't find it. I don't know if that removes the file from GitHub altogether though, once that commit is no longer referenced.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history)